# Creating extension for Notification.Name

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsnotificationcenter, swift5

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@dmytro.anokhin/notification-in-swift-d47f641282fa) for Notification Center, and it suggests to create an extension for `Notification.Name` to handle all names, so I created a new Swift file called `Notification+Name.swift` with these contents:

```
import Foundation

extension Notification.Name {
    static let URLContainerDidAddURL = NSNotification.Name("URLContainerDidAddURL")
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> 'Name' is not a member type of 'Notification'

What's going on? Why am I getting this?

Comment: Unable to reproduce this in Swift 5. Copied your code into a project and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```swift
 extension Notification.Name {
    static let URLContainerDidAddURL = Notification.Name("URLContainerDidAddURL")
}
```

Comment: I get an addition error `Type 'Notification' has no member 'Name'` on that line now